# Excel Pivot field dates do not group after text entries are fixed

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I've been running into this issue with pivot tables where, when a user copies & pastes dates as text, the pivot table date field ungroups and will not regroup even after fixing the data.

Here is a sample worksheet with the issue: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AgQyzBn90YbTot8U0u6SZqYpzR_EfQ.

Here are the steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Open up the attached document. Columns A & B are the source for the pivot table. Note that the dates are grouped by month (which I want).
2. Copy the "text dates" from column E into the "Date" column--just ctrl-c/v, not paste values or anything special. Be sure not to overwrite the header, just the data.
3. Refresh the pivot table. Note that the dates aren't grouped anymore, which makes sense because only dates group that way.
4. Copy the real dates (from column F) into Column A to fix the data issue.
5. Refresh the pivot table. Try to group the dates. Observe that they can no longer be grouped. WHY? It's the same data as before! Adding & removing fields doesn't help.
6. Change the source data to A1:B571 (the actual data range rather than the entire columns). The dates are now groupable.
7. Follow steps 2-5. Note that the same issue occurs when the entire column isn't selected.
8. Change the source data to A:B (entire columns). The dates are now groupable again.

How can I force Excel to interpret the data correctly--the way it does when first analyzing that field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon a bizarre solution: click "Refresh" twice, and you will be allowed to group the dates again.

No idea why, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

**If you have tried all the "make sure your dates are really in date format" Q&A for Excel PivotTable Group By Date issues and are still unable to make it work, read on.**

## Bottom Line Up Front:

- Launch the dialogue to create your PivotTable by selecting your data range in the worksheet, then select INSERT->PivotTable. A small dialogue window will appear.
- At the bottom of the dialogue, you *may* see a line that says:

`Choose whether you want to analyze multiple tables`
followed by
 `_ Add this data to the Data Model`

- In my case, the `_ Add this data to the Data Model` defaults to being checked. When I un-checked this option and then created the PivotTable, Group By is no longer grayed out in the PivotTable context menu (accessed by right-clicking in the column of dates in the PivotTable)--and everything works.

## Background:

I run Excel 2013 on Windows 10.

I have had similar issues in recent months, and I've been banging my head on the keyboard looking for a solution across the Interwebs. I believe the problem stems from Data Models in Excel 2013 and 2016 (I use 2013). For more on Data Models and how they can be used, see [this Microsoft help page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-Data-Model-in-Excel-87e7a54c-87dc-488e-9410-5c75dbcb0f7b). I realized that my problem with Group By being grayed out in Pivot Tables started when I added some add-ins to Excel (Power Query, Power Pivot, etc.) that relate to Data Models.

That's when I noticed the last section in the "Create PivotTable" dialogue mentions the Data Model.

Once I started un-checking this option in the Create PivotTable dialogue, I have been able to Group By dates in the PivotTable.

I had actually started using Python and Pandas to do some of my analysis that needs this type of group-by capability. I love Pandas and am finding all sorts of ways to use its awesomeness--but finding this fix to my Excel 2013 problem is a big time saver for me.

I hope this helps some of the many other people I've seen with similar Excel 2013/2016 Group By problems.